# RestSharp, Forge API - Getting error:overlapping ranges on file upload

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge

I am trying to upload a file to a bucket using the forge .NET SDK. It works most of the time but gives an {error: overlapping ranges} occasionally. Here is the code snippet.

```
private string uploadFileToBucket(Configuration configuration, string bucketKey, string filePath)
{
    ObjectsApi objectsApi = new ObjectsApi(configuration);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string base64EncodedUrn, objectKey;
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        long contentLength = fileStream.Length;
        string content_range = "bytes 0-" + (contentLength - 1) + "/" + contentLength;
        dynamic result = objectsApi.UploadChunk(bucketKey, fileName, (int)fileStream.Length, content_range,
            "12313", fileStream);
        DynamicJsonResponse dynamicJsonResponse = (DynamicJsonResponse)result;
        JObject json = dynamicJsonResponse.ToJson();

        JToken urn = json.GetValue("objectId");
        string urnStr = urn.ToString();
        base64EncodedUrn = ApiClient.encodeToSafeBase64(urnStr);
        objectKey = fileName;
    }
    return base64EncodedUrn;
}
```

Comment: May I know why the file you uploaded didn't be split into serval chucks in the above code snippet, it seems that you're trying to upload full file length in a single chunk via resumable API. Why not use [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/)?

Answer (score 1):

Before uploading, the file content must have to read to the computer memory, otherwise, the `FileStream` object in your code snippet is empty.

However, I would like to advise you to use [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/) instead if you want to upload the whole file in a single chunk only. Here is my test code. Hope it helps~

```
    private static TwoLeggedApi oauth2TwoLegged;
    private static dynamic twoLeggedCredentials;
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

     // Initialize the 2-legged OAuth 2.0 client, and optionally set specific scopes.
    private static void initializeOAuth()
    {
        // You must provide at least one valid scope
        Scope[] scopes = new Scope[] { Scope.DataRead, Scope.DataWrite, Scope.BucketCreate, Scope.BucketRead };

        oauth2TwoLegged = new TwoLeggedApi();
        twoLeggedCredentials = oauth2TwoLegged.Authenticate(FORGE_CLIENT_ID, FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET, oAuthConstants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS, scopes);
        objectsApi.Configuration.AccessToken = twoLeggedCredentials.access_token;
    }

    private static void uploadFileToBucket(string bucketKey, string filePath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*****Start uploading file to the OSS");
        string path = filePath;

        //File Total size
        var info = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        long fileSize = info.Length;

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            string sessionId = RandomString(12);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("sessionId: {0}", sessionId));

            long contentLength = fileSize;
            string content_range = "bytes 0-" + (contentLength - 1) + "/" + contentLength;
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading range： " + content_range);


            byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

            int nb = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)contentLength);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, nb);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            dynamic response = objectsApi.UploadChunk(bucketKey, info.Name, (int)contentLength, content_range,
                sessionId, memoryStream);

            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        initializeOAuth();
        uploadFileToBucket(BUCKET_KEY, FILE_PATH);
    }
```